# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Host,

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I keep getting this error when I'm trying to load a CRM project in Visual Studio 2013:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Host,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you running the project from a zip file without unzipping it?

Comment: Check this post once https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q275153

Answer (score 3):

Extract the contents of *CrmDeveloperToolsVS12_Installer.msi*

1. Open a Command Prompt as Administrator
2. Navigate to: `sdk\Tools\DeveloperToolkit\`
3. Run: `msiexec /a CrmDeveloperToolsVS12_Installer.msi /qb TARGETDIR=<EXTRACTFOLDER>`

Be sure to copy the contents of the CRM MSBUILD folder you extracted from the msi package to: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\CRM`

Then you have to edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config` and add the following lines:

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Windows.Design.Host" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Hope this will help.